# How to extract specific value between slashes in a URL?

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

I'm working on *.xml file containing pictures.

```
<pictures>https://images.example.co.uk/products/1835/1835776/large2/29203852.jpg|https://images.example.co.uk/products/1835/1835776/large2/29203856.jpg|https://images.example.co.uk/products/1835/1835776/large2/29203863.jpg|https://images.example.co.uk/products/1835/1835776/large2/29203880.jpg|https://images.example.co.uk/products/1835/1835776/large2/29203859.jpg|https://images.example.co.uk/products/1835/1835776/large2/29203853.jpg|https://images.example.co.uk/products/1835/1835776/large2/29203858.jpg|https://images.example.co.uk/products/1835/1835776/large2/29074560.jpg|https://images.example.co.uk/products/1835/1835776/large2/29203854.jpg|https://images.example.co.uk/products/1835/1835776/large2/29203860.jpg|https://images.example.co.uk/products/1835/1835776/large2/29203876.jpg|https://images.example.co.uk/products/1835/1835776/large2/29203862.jpg|https://images.example.co.uk/products/1835/1835776/large2/29203877.jpg|https://images.example.co.uk/products/1835/1835776/large2/29074561.jpg|https://images.example.co.uk/products/1835/1835776/large2/29203871.jpg|https://images.example.co.uk/products/1835/1835776/large2/29203873.jpg|https://images.example.co.uk/products/1835/1835776/large2/29203865.jpg|https://images.example.co.uk/products/1835/1835776/large2/29203874.jpg|https://images.example.co.uk/products/1835/1835776/large2/29203866.jpg|https://images.example.co.uk/products/1835/1835776/large2/29203872.jpg|https://images.example.co.uk/products/1835/1835776/large2/29203868.jpg|https://images.example.co.uk/products/1835/1835776/large2/29203867.jpg|https://images.example.co.uk/products/1835/1835776/large2/29203870.jpg|https://images.example.co.uk/products/1835/1835776/large2/29074558.jpg|https://images.example.co.uk/products/1835/1835776/large2/29203879.jpg|https://images.example.co.uk/products/1835/1835776/large2/29203864.jpg|https://images.example.co.uk/products/1835/1835776/large2/29203878.jpg|https://images.example.co.uk/products/1835/1835776/large2/29203881.jpg</pictures>
```

I need to extract **product ID** from the first image URL https://images.example.co.uk/products/1835/1835776/large2/29203852.jpg which for this example is **1835776**.

**Question**:

What is the correct regular expression to achieve this, considering that some elements within the image URL seperated with **/** are different for each product (XXXXX)?

```
https://images.example.co.uk/products/XXXXX/[I-WANT-THIS-ELEMENT]/large2/XXXXXXXX.jpg
```

Comment: [Parsing HTML with regex is hard job](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4234491/372239)

Comment: What did you try so far? Or is this a job request?

Comment: I would just use a class like NET_absolute, and feed it your url and then all you would have to do is call $url->getPart ( 2 );

Comment: `~../\d+/(\d+)/large2/...~` or `parse_url()`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Presuming the URL will always be in the same format:

```
$url = "https://images.example.co.uk/products/XXXXX/[I-WANT-THIS-ELEMENT]/large2/XXXXXXXX.jpg";
$url = explode('/',$url);
$id = $url[5];
echo $id;
```

Comment: Solved! Thank you :)